# Traveling from Germany to Austria without a passport at hand, with Blue card - plastic card "Aufenthaltstitel" but also says Pass(Ersatz)

Tags: schengen, germany, passport-renewals, austria, blue-card

I have a passport, but I left it in my embassy to renew. I would like to travel shortly to Austria and back. I have a German Aufenthaltstitel, due to having a "Blue Karte EU", and it says on the card Pass(ersatz) bis 09 09 2022

As far as I understood Aufenthaltstitel is only valid in Germany ([Can I take a flight within Germany on my Blue card if I do not have a passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/149622/can-i-take-a-flight-within-germany-on-my-blue-card-if-i-do-not-have-a-passport)), but it says Pass(ersatz) - does it mean I can use it to travel within the EU?

Comment: _Pass(ersatz)_ is a concept of German law, so that notation has no meaning outside of Germany.  Austria, however, might tolerate visitors from Schengen countries who have only their residence permits and not their passports, though I doubt it.  Are you flying, taking a train or bus, or making your own way across the border?

Comment: See https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-nationals/index_en.htm

Comment: Traveling by train. Last time I traveled to Vienna, I was asked for my documents on the border crossing back to Germany. As far as I remember, Aufenthaltstitel was enough for them

Comment: @Traveller that page is focused on people entering from outside the Schengen area.  As romand's experience shows, it's often possible to cross the interior border with only a residence permit, even if that document is technically insufficient by itself.  The more critical question for romand is what would happen if the Austrians check on the way in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The notation **Pass(Ersatz)** shows that the **Aufenthaltstitel** is an identity document.

It is **not** listed as an acceptable replacement for a passport to enter Germany.

The [Schengen acquis](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:42000A0922(02)) also states that a valid travel document **together** with the residence permit is required:

> **Article 21**: 1. *Aliens who hold valid residence permits issued by one of the Contracting Parties may, on the basis of **that permit and a valid travel document**, move freely for up to three months within the territories of the other Contracting Parties, provided that they fulfil the entry conditions referred to in Article 5(1)(a)...*

When the new **Entry/Exit System (EES)** is introduced, the **Schengen Border Code** will have to be changed in many parts.
Unfortunately, there has been no hint as to whether a residence permit will be re-classified as a valid travel document within the Schengen Area.

---

The German word **Pass** is (legally) **not** the same a **Passport** (in German: **Reisepass**).

It is an identity document that everyone over 15 must in some form have. A Passport is the main form of a **Pass**.

An ID-Card (**Personalausweis**) is a **Passersatz** (Pass replacement) that fulfills the Pass requirement.

An **Aufenthaltstitel** is, a **Passersatz** that fulfills the Pass requirement so that it can be used as an identity document for 3rd country nationals.
It is **not** listed in the §3,4 AufenthV as an acceptable **Passersatz** to enter Germany:

- [§3 - Zulassung nichtdeutscher amtlicher Ausweise als Passersatz (AufenthV)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthv/__3.html) lists the non-German documents that are accepted as a **Passersatz**

  - including ID-Cards of EU Citizens
- [§4 - Deutsche Passersatzpapiere für Ausländer](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthv/__4.html) lists the German documents issue to foreigners that are accepted as a **Passersatz**

  - including Refugee and Stateless passports

Comment: Yet romand was able to enter Germany from Austria by train after showing only the residence permit to the officers who checked.  How do you explain that?  I think the more likely problem with this plan is the possibility of being checked by Austrian officers.

Comment: @phoog, it would be an example of the officer *either* being unaware of the fine points of the law (yes, that happens), *or* willing to make a judgement call to accept the German document for this purpose (that should have come with a verbal reminder to bring a passport next time). Government officials overlook minor infractions quite often, one just shouldn't rely on it happening every time.

Comment: @o.m. Yes, §3(2): *In justified individual cases, the Federal Ministry of the Interior **or the body designated by it may permit exemptions from the passport requirement for the purpose of crossing the border** before the foreigner enters the federal territory, and for a subsequent stay of up to six months.*

Comment: @MarkJohnson, that would then have to be documented. The comment talked about an intra-Schengen border, and simply overlooking a minor issue.

Comment: @o.m. yes, that's what I would have thought, too, except that under the Schengen borders code, checks at the internal border (in the absence of the formal reintroduction of systematic internal controls, at least) are supposed to be conducted as any routine document check on the country's territory, and, for such a check in Germany, the _Passersatz_ residence card suffices.  The problem here really is Austria, not Germany.

Comment: Intra-Schengen checks a lot of times are superficial and they accept anything seemingly official, especially if you are returning to your "home" country. One of my friends was allowed to pass a border check with just a bad quality photocopy of his German residence permit. This doesn't mean that this is valid and that you will always be let go, so it's better to be on the safe side of the law and have everything required with you.